# is it possible to pass a value from variable to variable?

Tags: xml, vb.net

here i got a module with a variable of ip_add for datasource, datastr for database name, userstr for user id and passstr for password...

[image]

and here is my form..my problem is..why there is no value appears in the constr ? but in the textbox it appears without a probz..what's wrong with this ? is it not possible to pass a value from a form to the variables in the module ?

[image]

i'm kinda stuck here..tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this. Add this code in your module.

```
Public Sub SET_GLOBAL_VARS(Byval pIP_Address As String, Byval pDataString As String, _
                           Byval pUserString As String, Byval pPassString As String) 
    ip_add = pIP_Address
    datastr = pDataString
    userstr = pUserString
    passstr = pPassString
End Sub

Public Function GET_GLOBAL_CONSTR() As String
     constr = "your connection string here"
     Return constr
End Function
```

and to use it,

```
For (condition)
   ...
   SET_GLOBAL_VARS(Ip_Add, datastr, userstr, passstr)
   MsgBox(GET_GLOBAL_CONSTR())
End Loop
```

PS: Please avoid using images as substitute to the codes.. just copy it and paste it as text in your question :)

Comment: sorry about the image though..i just want to show it clearly with the showed form and the msgbox..i'll try that mate..

Comment: Don't worry, it's OK :). I was also doing that before, and then someone from SO told me the same.

Comment: btw..the last code with the for loop ? still in the module ?

Comment: no, it is on your `for loop`, under `btn6_Click`. Are you sure you want to use it like that? If there are many records on your xml file, that would only set the module variables on the LAST loop..

Comment: it works..tnx..but can do some a little explaination ? how and why it didn't work ? and yours do ?

Comment: On the module, you have to set the variables first, that's what the `SET` function do, after setting you can get the variable by using the `GET`. However, on your code, I can't really answer you that because I myself isn't sure why (i'm a newbie), I have tried that too but it isn't working.